# Postgresql Date from Timestamp to String in Java

Tags: java, string, postgresql, date

I am getting a timestamp as date from my postgres database with the format of yyyy-MM-dd. But the problem is that I have to get table entries BETWEEN two dates, but the date format does not have the Between operator.

```sql
Select jiraissue.project as ProjectID, project.pname, coalesce(sum(worklog.timeworked),0) as timeworked
from jiraissue, worklog, project
where jiraissue.project = 11350 
and jiraissue.id = worklog.issueid and jiraissue.project = project.id
and date(worklog.updated) BETWEEN 2015-09-16 AND 2015-09-30
group by timeworked, project, project.id
```

Now postgres wants an explicit cast, probably to a String, but to_char in front if the date wo't work either. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Select jiraissue.project as ProjectID, project.pname, coalesce(sum(worklog.timeworked),0) as timeworked
from jiraissue, worklog, project
where jiraissue.project = 11350 
and jiraissue.id = worklog.issueid and jiraissue.project = project.id
and date(worklog.updated) >= '2015-09-16'::date 
and date(worklog.updated) <= '2015-09-30'::date 
group by timeworked, project, project.id
```

Assuming you're on the most recent stable version (9.4), [this section of the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html) covers the topic of date/time handling. You might also want to check the [SQL expressions for type casting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS), which is the `::` bit in the solution.

Comment: thank, will accept the answer when I am able to do it in 5 minutes :)